# Find out origin of Google Pub/Sub subscriptions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, subscription, google-cloud-pubsub

We are using Google Pub/Sub in the Google Cloud Platform.

There are many anonymous subscriptions listening to our topics. We don't know how and why they have been created.

Is there a way to find out who (e.g. which program, which host, etc.) has created a subscription?

Comment: If you keep, or export, your Stackdriver logs, you will find who created the subscriptions and when. The "why" will be unknown. Stackdriver can give you a lot of information. If you enable audit logging even more (review pricing first).

Comment: @JohnHanley OK, thank you. Do you know where I can find them in the Stackdriver?

Comment: Kamal just posted the answer about Stackdriver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at the [activity log](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity) for the project to get information about the creation of subscriptions. Under "Resource type" under "Filter," you can choose "Cloud Pub/Sub Subscription":

[image: activity]

This will bring up a list of all subscription activity. You can select "Cloud Pub/Sub Topic" to see all topic activity.

Comment: Just for completeness, you can also use a Stackdriver logging filter of resource.type="pubsub_subscription" to see subscription creation information.